# Swift Closures as field in Tuple

Tags: swift, types, closures, tuples

I'm trying to create a Simple HTTP Framework.

At first I have the following typealias:

```
typealias successBock = ([Any]) -> ()
typealias errorBlock = (NSError) -> ()
typealias requestResponseTuple = (con: NSURLConnection, success: successBock?, error: errorBlock?)
```

And I have an error in this method:

```
func performHttpRequest<T>(method: HTTPRequestMethod, path: String?, parameter:Dictionary<String, String>,
    success:successBock?, error:errorBlock?) -> Int {
        var url = NSURL(string: baseURL.stringByAppendingPathComponent((path != nil) ? path! : ""))
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 20.0)
        var con = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
        var requestId = newRequestId()
        currentActiveRequests[requestId] = requestResponseTuple(con, successBock.self, errorBlock.self)
        return requestId;
}
```

The error goes here:

```
requestResponseTuple(con, success, errorBlock.self)
```

Error: "'successBock.Type' is not convertible to 'successBock'"

**I want to pass the block, so that i'm able to call it later.** In objective-c i never had a problem like that.

To be honest, i have no idea why this occurs. I checked several pages, but didn't found a solution.

Best regards,

Maik

---

edit2:
changed one method:

```
func performHttpRequest<T>(method: HTTPRequestMethod, path: String?, parameter:Dictionary<String, String>,
    success:successBock?, error:errorBlock?) -> Int {
        var url = NSURL(string: baseURL.stringByAppendingPathComponent((path != nil) ? path! : ""))
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 20.0)
        var con = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
        var requestId = newRequestId()
        currentActiveRequests[requestId] = requestResponseTuple(con, success, error)
        return requestId;
}
```

Error now: Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments

Edit:

CodeLink:
http://pastebin.com/c5a0fn1N http://pastebin.com/d0QGQ2AR

Comment: What do you want to do with successBock.self ?
firstly i suggest you to Capitalize you type alias so you will easily differentiate types from variables Names.

Comment: at first i haven't had .self. Xcode suggested id.

Comment: edit: I want to pass the block, so that i'm able to call it later. In objective-c i never had a problem like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok if i understand well you just have to change

```
requestResponseTuple(con, successBock.self, errorBlock.self)
```

by

```
requestResponseTuple(con!, success, error)
```

Your parameter Names are success and error. successBock and errorBlock are the types.
So i Suggest you to capitalize them.
Hope it helps you.

edit: Since `NSURLConnection` returns an optional, you have to unwrap it.
You should check if con is equal to nil before unwrapping it.

```
if let con = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
        {
            currentActiveRequests[requestId] = RequestResponseTuple(con, success, error)
        }
        else
        {
                // there was an error, the NSURLConnection has not been created
        }
```

Comment: So for the new error That mean that you can't do currentActiveRequests[requestId].
what is the type of currentActiveRequests? I ll edit my answer.

Comment: private var currentActiveRequests: Dictionary<Int, requestResponseTuple>

Comment: So newRequestId() returns an Int?

Comment: hum. It's strange i try it in the playground and for me currentActiveRequests[requestId] = requestResponseTuple(nil, nil, nil);
works.
Are you sure that currenctActiveRequests is well declarated?

Comment: When I try your code there is an error because of HTTPRequestMethod.What is it?

Comment: Ok, it's just an exclamation mark issue... Optionals can be disturbing :)
replace that:
       currentActiveRequests[requestId] = RequestResponseTuple(con, success, error)
by 
       currentActiveRequests[requestId] = RequestResponseTuple(con!, success, error)
add exclamation mark after con since NSURLConnection returns an NSURLConnection?

Comment: I just edit the answer with a good practice, you should take a look.